# Should we always specify ToString() explicitly?

Tags: c#, object-oriented-analysis

I have a custom class structure as follows.

```
public interface Stuff { }
public Thing : Stuff 
{ 
  public new String ToString() { return "That's the thing!"; } 
}
```

Then, in other parts of my code I have a method that takes a *String* object as a parameter. The first line compiles, while the second one doesn't. I thought that *ToString* was called by default when sending in an object. And *Stuff*, being inherited from *Object* class should have *ToString* already implemented (and also, in my case, shadowed by **my** implementation).

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
MustHaveString(thing.ToString());
MustHaveString(thing);
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Why would you declare a *new* `ToString` method rather than overriding the existing one? Ick! (But no, ToString isn't generally called automatically.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Because according to [the internet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65e02299-300f-4b74-8f0a-679f490605f5/new-vs-override-), the *override* can be used on *virtual* methods and *ToString* in *Object* isn't.

Comment: @KonradViltersten `ToString` *is* virtual.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. All reference type objects derive from object, ence all this objects have a `ToString` method.
When you make complex types, generally what the `ToString` method does is outputting the class name of the invoking object (since it wasn't overridden). So where do you have a problem? :)

Comment: `ToString` certainly is `virtual`. See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx)

Comment: @Servy In *that* case, I've got no case, haha. However, it seems that the heave downvote will give me a new badge, haha. The question **will** be removed.   :D

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet In the way that I didn't check the docs. Just assumed it. I'm going to put my head into a place where sun doesn't shine now. Thanks.   :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `MustHaveString` looks something like:

```
public void MustHaveString(string arg)
```

Then simply saying `thing` results in a compile error, unless `thing` has an implicit conversion to `string`. Without the implicit conversion, you must do `thing.ToString()`.  If, however, your code is like:

```
string myString = "This is a thing: " + thing;
```

Then the `ToString` is implicitly called, so it's optional.

In most cases, I would recommend explicitly calling the `ToString` method, to make it clear to people reading your code what's going on.

Edit: since this answer was accepted, I thought I should also mention that you should make your `ToString()` method an `override`, not a `new`. This will result in the normally-expected behavior, which is what I described above.

Answer (score 10):

You're probably getting confused because of calls such as `String.Format` and `Console.WriteLine`, as well as string concatenation operator, which call `ToString` implcitly.

This *isn't* a general rule though. In general, if you need a string, you need to either call `ToString` explicitly or have some other conversion. I wouldn't recommend creating implicit conversions to `string` - they're likely to cause more pain than joy.

I'd *also* recommend against creating a new `ToString` method. Instead, you should override the one declared by `object`. Hiding methods is almost always a bad idea; there are a few cases where you really want to do it (e.g. to change the return type) but it should be avoided where possible.